# How to upgrade laravel 5.5 to laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to update from Laravel 5.5 to 10. My php version is 8.1.5 but facing many problems to update directly here. Especially ,

```
 requires php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

if it can't be updated directly, what steps should be taken? I have attached my Composer json file below.

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.4",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "^2.5",
    "intervention/image": "^2.4",
    "laravel/framework": "10",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf": "^3.1",
    "shipu/php-aamarpay-payment": "^1.0",
    "milon/barcode": "^5.2",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables": "1.5"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0",
    "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "database/seeds",
      "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/"
    }
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": []
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
      "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
      "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
  },
  "extra": {
    "laravel": {
      "dont-discover": [
        "laravel/dusk"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to take version 8 first, then 9 and 10 one by one, but mPDF caused the most problems.

Please help me I am beginner.

Comment: So you need to follow a step by step upgrade given here https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade. Also make sure you don't jump to any version by skipping previous. Mostly high impact changes are the ones to look out for.

Comment: Also the php version in your composer needs to be upgraded. The upgrade docs will tell you about this as well

Comment: If all else fails, create a new project for 10, add your dependencies in one-by-one, and then start adding your code back in. There's also [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/) that will do the work for you, though it's paid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel provides a full and understandable documentation on how to update Laravel. You could upgrade directly from Laravel 5.5.0 to Laravel 10.x, but it could create a lot of errors that will be difficult to understand and to solve. I suggest you follow this process and upgrade your project to each version before by following the versionning order, you start by 5.5.0 to 5.6, then 5.6 to 5.7, 5.7 to 5.8, 5.8 to 6.x, 6.x to 7.x, 7.x to 8.x, 8.x to 9.x and 9.x to 10.x

Here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade#upgrade-5.6.0) from where you should start.
Just to be clear I am not saying you cannot upgrad directly from Laravel 5.5.0 to Laravel 10. I've already did it with Laravel 5.7 to Laravel 9.x. I don't remember exactly every step, but I remember that I did this

1. I created a Laravel 9.x project, installed the dependencies I wanted in it.
2. I made a copy of the project in Laravel 5.7 (In case for backup)
3. I took the composer.json from the Laravel 9.x project and I copied it in the copy of the Laravel 5.7 project
4. Then I ran the command composer update in the copy of the project in Laravel 5.7

After that there were a lot of errors from Laravel framework components, I solved them all one by one, it took me an afternoon. I would have avoid all this error solving if I would have followed every upgrade documentation and followed the versionning in order.

If you are curious [here](https://github.com/Dolotboy/Laravel9.x-Facebook-Login) is my project in Laravel 9.x and you can see the fork attached to it is in Laravel 5.7 and it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

**A little background:**

A `composer.json` file is an important part of any PHP package. The `require` and `require-dev` sections are a place where you list out the external packages that your code *depends* on. Within these sections you have control over which versions of these external packages can/should be installed. This means you can exclude any versions that prove to break your code. Usually there will be a range of valid version (accomplished by [version constraints](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#writing-version-constraints)) although sometimes it may be only one exact version.

Just like your code is a package (in part because it has a `composer.json` file) , every package that you include in your `require` and `require-dev` sections has a `composer.json` file of their own. And just like you get to specify your dependencies and their versions, each external package gets to specify those for itself.

When you run `composer update`, composer looks through every `composer.json` file recursively and and tries to find 1 single version for every required package that satisfies every package's require sections. If it's successful, composer installs the packages. If not, you'll get an error like: `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.` Followed by more detail about the issues.

**Answer**

It would be helpful if you would post your entire composer error message. But since you are specifying and PHP version greater than 7.0 in your `composer.json`, but composer is showing you that ^7.3 is required, I'm guessing that PHP ^7.3 (which means any version 7.3 <= version < 8.0 where 8.0 isn't included. see version constraint link above) is a requirement of one of your dependency packages. So you'll need to identify which package is forcing you to stay on PHP 7 and upgrade it.

If you do this one by one, you'll probably fix one issue just to run into another. Since Laravel 10 is the latest version, a good place to start may be with the latest version of each of your dependencies. You can run `composer outdated -D` to get a list of all your dependencies, which version they are on, and the most up-to-date version that exists. I might try updating all your dependencies to the latest version and go from there (help on that in [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md).

Once all of your packages have resolved and installed, you may start getting errors when you run your code. There's often breaking changes from one version to the next, so reading through the upgrade guides for each previous version may be valuable.